# Single HTML Form to Multiple PHP Scripts

Tags: php, html, forms

I am somewhat new to PHP programming and I have question about the best way to handle input from the same form that can go to two different PHP pages.

For example I have a database of projects and parameters, from which users can select relevant options then submit the form to either a preview script, which displays some of the data on a new page, or a download option which allows users to download the selected data in CSV format.

```
<input type="submit" value="download" name ="download"/>
<input type="submit" value="preview" name="preview"/>
```

Currently the input is sent to a single PHP script which uses an if statement to determine the best course of action

```
if($_POST['download']){
...
}else if($_POST['preview']){
...
}
```

But this seems like a messy way to go about handling this situation.  Is there an easy way and/or a best practice for

1. creating a handler PHP script that then passes relevant information to another more specific PHP file, in this example I could split download and preview into `download.php` and `preview.php`

Or

2. Reuse entries from a form from one PHP script to another, for example a user presses the preview button, looks at data on the new page, decides it is acceptable and would like to download the full data set by pressing a download button on the preview page.  Is it possible to make that download button use the same script I already have i.e. go back and take the other `if` branch from the same script that generated the preview?

I attempted to find other related answers, but was hoping for a solution that does not require javascript, though I would be open to using js if that is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much already have your handler script, although I think I would refer to it as a simple router, and the scripts it uses are the handlers. You can just modify it to include the appropriate script depending on the selected value.

```
if ($_POST['download']) {
    include 'download.php';
} else if($_POST['preview']) {
    include 'preview.php';
}
```

As far as reusing the user's selected options from preview to download, there are different ways to handle that. One is to insert those values into hidden inputs in a form in your preview script with `action="download.php"`. Another is to store them in the session.

In this case the first option would be simpler, because your download script would be able to just use the values from `$_POST` regardless of whether the user went straight to download or used preview first.

Comment: Are there any security concerns with saving variables in a session vs creating a form and using `$_POST`?  I like this solution and the idea of filling in a hidden form.  If I were so inclined I could probably even write another script to fill in the hidden form on several pages if needed, is that correct?

Comment: A user with a little understanding and malicious intent could easily replace the values in the hidden form, but this is irrelevant because these would be the same values you would be allowing them to directly input if they did not go through the preview step first. I don't believe there would be any specific security concerns that depend on whether you get the values from $_POST or $_SESSION. The security concerns only begin when you start actually doing things with those values.

Comment: Some of the values can be used as part of SQL queries, so it seems like I could add input validation to a script that automatically fills in the hidden table, though the same input validation steps will be necessary before storing variables in a session as well I would imagine.

Comment: The same steps would be necessary either way you decide to pass the values around. However, although validation is good for checking whether the user has entered appropriate values and informing them if they have not, it should not be used as a substitute for properly escaping the values for use in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you inputs have `value` attributes, you can try doing like this :

```
<input type="submit" value="download" name ="submit_type"/>
<input type="submit" value="preview" name="submit_type"/>
```

and in your php :

```
if ('download' == $_POST['submit_type']) {
    // ...
} else if('preview' == $_POST['submit_type']) {
    // ...
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it out there, but this one works.

Comment: This seems like a good way to expand if/when I decide to expand the options from the data selection page to include additional things that might be useful for users, thanks for pointing it out.